# Angular 4 and Spring boot - 404 page not found

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

need your help here please.

I have a login page. After I enter username/password, I want to see Dashboard page. But I am getting 404 page not found. Can anyone please tell what is going on here.

When I hit http://localhost:8080 -> It goes to http://localhost:8080/login - Which is expected.

After I enter username/password, it goes to http://localhost:8080 - **Expected: to go to Dashboard page i.e. http://localhost:8080/dashboard**
[image]
[image]

```
@Component
public class SimpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
 @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
       ...
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "dashboard");
    }
```

DashboardController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dashboard")
public class DashboardController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String init(){
        System.out.println("Dashboard - init()");
        return "dashboard_init";
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```
Hello... {{name}}
  Hello... {{title}}
<h1>
    Welcome {{title}}!
  </h1>
<p>Id: <span>{{greeting.id}}</span></p>
    <p>Message: <span>{{greeting.content}}!</span></p>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import {DashboardComponent} from "./dashboard/dashboard.component";
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
 //   { path: 'dashboard', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'dashboard_init',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        data: { title: 'Dashboard' }
    }
];
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-component',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    private currentAssociate: Associate;

    constructor(private http: Http,
                private router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // initialize services and data
        this.http
            .get('/dashboard')
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                let data = response.json();

                if (data.currentAssociate) this.currentAssociate = data.currentAssociate as Associate;
            })
            .catch(error => {
             //   this.alertService.error(error);
            });
    }
}
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Dashboard</title> 
</head>

<div>
<B>Dashboard...</B>
</div>
</html>
```

[image]
**Error: (When the url is http://localhost:8080/dashboard/)**

```
Dashboard - init()
[2m2018-03-26 10:07:20.421[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m13184[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36morg.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine            [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-2] Exception processing template "dashboard_init": Error resolving template "dashboard_init", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
[2m2018-03-26 10:07:20.422[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m13184[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "dashboard_init", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "dashboard_init", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
```

Comment: What do you get if you write http://localhost:8080/dashboard to the address bar and hit enter?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/dashboard -> it is redirecting to http://localhost:8080 with same error (i.e. 404)...     But with http://localhost:8080/dashboard / -> it is throwing 500 error. Updated screenshot

Comment: Why did you implement DashboardController? once your server angular resources, angular routing should take care of routing to different pages.

Comment: With what purpose you return dashboard_init in String init()

Comment: @EduardoEljaiek and Vikram: Here is what all I want. Once I hit Login button in Login page, I want to see the url as localhost:8080/dashboard with the contents from dashboard html. So my understanding was once I redirect to "dashboard" from onAuthenticationSuccess(), it will go to DashboardController and there it redirects to "dashboard_init", then in app-routing.module.ts, it will get the path and display dashboard html. I know I am wrong somewhere. need help. Thanks a lot for your time to look into the question.

Comment: @SKumar skip the call to DashboartController, and onAuthenticationSuccess() use the angular routing directly to forward the page to Dashboard screen.In simple words the angular app should not have any routing dependencies on back end application.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi: Are you saying comment out this code: redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "dashboard");  If yes, any other changes?

Comment: @Skumar Spring cannot route an Angular application. When compiled they are loaded up into bundles and so you need Javascript to call the templates. They are not rendered server-side. See https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5 for how to route Angular

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular not routing to desired page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515838/angular-not-routing-to-desired-page)

Comment: You can use the @RestController annotation and return some json data. And accordingly redirect to the required component in Angular itself.

Answer (score 0):

something wrong overall.. 
in Controller replace top /dashboard with /

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class DashboardController {

   @RequestMapping("/")
   String init(){
       System.out.println("Dashboard - init()");
      return "dashboard_init";
   }
}
```

Also as fas as I remember return "dashboard_init"  is expecting dashboard_init.html template to be returned

Probably you want redirect or something to /dashboard_init, do like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void index(final HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    response.sendRedirect( "/wherever-you-want");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please give a little more details. I didn't get not get what index() method... And here is what I want: Once I hit Login button in Login page, I want to see the url as localhost:8080/dashboard with the contents from dashboard html. So my understanding was once I redirect to "dashboard" from onAuthenticationSuccess(), it will go to DashboardController and there it redirects to "dashboard_init", then in app-routing.module.ts, it will get the path and display dashboard html. I know I am wrong somewhere. need help.

Answer (score 0):

This series of tutorials will help you to integrate Spring Security with Angular, using different approaches. Starting with Basic Auth

[Spring Security and Angular](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/)

Comment: Yes, I saw that, But it does not explain the way I wanted... :(