# Angular not routing to desired page

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am having an issue is seeing the dashboard page after login. Can anyone please tell what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

After I login, I see the url as http://localhost:8080/home. It never calls the method in DashboardController.java

app-routing.module.ts

```
import {DashboardComponent} from "./dashboard/dashboard.component";
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'dashboard', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        data: { title: 'Dashboard' }
    }
];
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-component',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    private currentAssociate: Associate;

    constructor(private http: Http,
                private router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // initialize services and data
        this.http
            .get('api/dashboard')
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                let data = response.json();

                if (data.currentAssociate) this.currentAssociate = data.currentAssociate as Associate;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                //alert("Error...");
             //   this.alertService.error(error);
            });

    }
}
```

DashboardController.java

```
@RestController
public class DashboardController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String init(){
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Dashboard - init()");
        return "dashboard_init";
    }
}
```

Comment: return "dashboard_init"; is the response you send back to client as a flag which would be used for route to the dashboard page? And you route to dashboard seems to be wrong. { path: 'dashboard', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi: I think return "dashboard_init" is just a string. I can return a object, list, json etc. I believe that doesn't have anything with routing... am I correct?

Comment: That's correct, so the problem is in routing config then { path: 'dashboard', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' } you see you are redirecting it to home here if you access dashboard page. If you correct it, the problem should go away.

Comment: are you saying it should be like this: { path: 'dashboard', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },

Comment: it can be { path: 'dashboard', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' } or  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Ok trying with this code. Lets see what is the result:const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    //{ path: 'dashboard', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        data: { title: 'Dashboard' }
    }
];

Comment: Now you are pointing home to dashboard and dashboard to home, please correct it.

Comment: my bad. actually I tried below, but no luck...:(     {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        data: { title: 'Dashboard' }
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167654/discussion-between-vikram-palakurthi-and-skumar).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your route definitions...

Comment: Here is a working StackBlitz with your routes. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-msrpnp
 If your endpoint isn't being reached it isn't a problem with your routes, there is something likely going wrong with your get request or your end point itself

Comment: @Narm: here is code I uploaded in an existing project in github. the project may not run as I renamed/deleted few files for security reasons, but I am sure once can see all code what I am trying to achieve. https://github.com/SudhirSahoo/spring/tree/master/main

Comment: @Narm: I can call the rest service and see the result. 
 When I hit this url, the method in the Controller is also being called. http://localhost:8080/api/dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the code, the app.component.html was missing the  which caused the routing not to work. Use this [link](https://github.com/SudhirSahoo/spring/commit/4a15663f001badec430369e1eb85fedc0e76dac3) to see the full commit.

changes in app.component.html, include

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Add a new Home component so that routes to /home will work.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
    }
];
```

Use the full path http://localhost:8080/api/dashboard to make calls to the DashboardController in Spring application.

```
this.http
    .get('http://localhost:8080/api/dashboard')              
    .toPromise()
```